# Split raster, define names of new rasters

Tags: split, raster

I've been searching for a solution for a couple of days, how i could split large georeferenced rasters into smaller ones in ArcMap. Of course, there's the "split raster" tool, that divides raster by features from polygon, but the raster names are assigned randomly. Instead i need to define the names of the new rasters- i split the raster using a shapefile cut from coordinate grid and the names of rasters should be the same as grid page numbers. I haven't worked with python at all, so is there any chance it can be done there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you use: Data Management Tools -> Raster -> Raster Processing -> Clip ?
Doesn't the result include feature id in name of produced raster or something like that? I guess this can be useful for hints: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84969/clip-raster-using-shapefile-into-multiple-rasters-using-arcgis-desktop
Can't remember exactly the method which provided feature id in filename when raster was clipped with fishnet in shp file.

Comment: Thank you- the method described in the link you shared of using a model builder and "clip raster" tool seems to have solved my problem!

Comment: Great to know. Although the fun thing is that most people find generating fishnet more challenging than the clipping itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can do that with `R`

```
library(raster)
# example data
r <- raster()
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)

# create blocks
a <- aggregate(raster(r), 60)
b <- as(a, 'SpatialPolygons')

f <- function(i) {
   fname <- paste0('raster_', i, '.tif')
   crop(r, extent(b[i,]), filename=fname)
}

x <- sapply(1:length(b), f)
```